# PRIMARY KEY for a table with 2 columns used for counting?

Tags: php, mysql

I have several tables that store 2 values, for example one of them is a table `likes` that  stores the id of the user who liked `user_id` (Auto increment, Primary key) and the `post_id` (Auto increment, Primary key).

```
"INSERT INTO likes (user_id, post_id) VALUES (value, value)"
```

Then to i use a count on the `post_id` and show them back to the page.

My question is do i need another unique Primary key(AI) on the `likes` table or do i make `post_id` as a Primary key since from what i know is faster to do select and counts on keys?

Comment: You do not **need** indices. Try to run your application and monitor if there is a performance issue

Comment: you should take likes table own primery key.
Becuase the user_id and post id are the foreign of this table.

Answer (score 0):

Create one unique index on two user_id and post_id field